# Is there a more general notion of "absolute value" for a field?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is there a more general notion of absolute values/norms that applies when the field in question is not a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$? My interest is that when we have a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, we can define a norm on $V$ based on how it plays with the absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$, and the metrics induced by these norms have a number of nice properties. However, all references I've found to normed spaces consider only spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. This is a shame, because Banach spaces are so dang nice to work with. Are there other fields on which one can define something like an "absolute value" which would allow the definition of a norm on a vector space over that field?

Comment: A field always has a trivial absolute value $|x| = 0$ when $x = 0$ and $|x| = 1$ otherwise, and for finite fields this is the only one. So the answer is yes, but now you might want to consider more interesting absolute values (therefore imposing the restriction of $0$ characteristic). I don't know much else unfortunately.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that would just generate the discrete topology, which I think is pretty clearly not the goal.

Comment: I know, but as I said I don't know much on the topic. I just wanted to resolve the question of existence :) I think that you might want to search for "valuations" though, or just "absolute value" in the context of abstract algebra.

Comment: Banach spaces are nice because you have convergence. When it comes down to it: complete, Archimedian, ordered-field. So the values of the norm must, practically speaking, lie in the Real numbers. And the underlying field must be an extension of $\mathbb{R}$. At least that's the way I see it.

Comment: @TrialAndError I'm not very familiar with the p-adic analysis, but is there not a valuation there? My understanding was that the p-adics extended the rationals, but not really the reals.